# pyspark is giving java.lang.StackOverflowError on union/unionAll funtion

Tags: pyspark, union

I'm trying to merge a dataframe inside a paginator for loop using union/unionAll function and dropping duplicates from it. The loop has thousands of iterations. when the number of iterations are in hundreds the code is working fine where as the same code is not able to handle thousands of iterations and giving.

> An error occured while calling o30984.union.
> : java.lang.StackOverflowError.

sample code:

let df1 -  is empty dataframe

```
for page in pages:
   for obj in page['Contents']:
      df2=spark.createDataframe(obj)
      df1=df1.unionAll(df2)
      df1.dropDuplicates(col)
      df1.write.csv(path)
```

here pages have length almost equal to 50,000 to hundreds of thousands and the schema of the both data frames is same.

Is there a better and more efficient way or any alternative for this?

i was expecting to get all the data frames merged perfectly in all the iterations and removing the duplicates from it.

Comment: it may be due to a large number of dataframes being appended. StackOverflowError is generally due to huge number of recursions.

Comment: Please use universal measurements and avoid using local words like *lakh*