# StackOverFlow error when merging dataframes

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, iteration, union-all

We have an object in S3 which has close to 100K files. We iterate over each of the file and generate the schema of it. The below PySpark code works for objects with 5K files but throws StackOverflow error for objects with higher number of files.

For objects with more than 500 files, it throws a StackOverFlow error in the unionAll line.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

PySpark code:

```
  schema_empty = structType([structField("col_name",StringType(),True), structField("data_type",StringType(),True)structField("file_name",StringType(),True)])
  
  schema_df = spark.createDataFrame([],schema_empty)

  schema_file = structType([structField("col_name",StringType(),True), structField("file_name",StringType(),True)])

  for page in pages:
     for obj in page['Contents']:
        s3_file = "s3://" + bucket + obj["Key"]
        df = spark.read.option("header","True").option("inferSchema","True").parquet(s3_file)
        col_list = df.dtypes
        df = spark.createDataFrame(col_list, schema_file)
        df_name = df.withColumn("filename",lit(s3_file))
        schema_df = schema_df.unionAll(df_name)
```

Comment: same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76102256/8279585)